# Pass img src via jquery to new div

Tags: jquery, image, variables, simplemodal

I am trying to create a "simple" modal type of operation.  When a user clicks on an image it opens a mask over the screen (done that) and displays the image (can't do that).  This is ment to be very simple, no need for galleries etc. hence just a simple effect.

The code generated for the mask is

```
$j(document).ready(function(){
$j('.postentry img').click(function(e) {  
e.preventDefault();  
var maskHeight = $j(document).height();  
var maskWidth = $j(window).width();  
$j('#mask').css({'width':maskWidth,'height':maskHeight});  
$j('#mask').fadeIn(1000);      
$j('#mask').fadeTo("slow",0.8);    
});
```

});

I can get the src of the image (but just forgotten the code) but it's abit like this

```
Sj('postentry img').att(src)
```

(Or something I did get it to dispaly properly in an alert but how do I pass that sc to a hidden div and display it above the mask (OK I assume that's z-index in the css) but it's more how do I display the image.

Help please  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do

```
$('.postentry img').attr('src', 'imageurl').show();
```

or just

```
$('.postentry img').attr('src', 'imageurl');
```

and then show the div containing the image using

```
$('#imagediv').show();
```

If you show your html I could give a definite answer. Also, the you don't need to put the j after $.

Comment: Ryan - actually the $j is to avoid no-conflict in WordPress - standard WP practice

Comment: Ah, I don't use wordpress that much :).  Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Its

```
$j('postentry img').attr(src)
```

See **[.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)**

and to show the image you can call the .show() method

```
$j('postentry img').attr('src', yourimageurl).show();
```

See **[.show()](http://api.jquery.com/show/)**

Comment: Nearly but not quiet, I can't get the image to open in a new div on click - infact onclick nothing happens (if I remove the mask)